# Saving image with UIImageJPEGRepresentation and using as UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to save an image [from here](http://skimap.org/data/1006/1/1242969662.jpg) to the device's Documents directory but my approach isn't working. 
I have to mention that this approach is working for picture [like this](https://irs2.4sqi.net/img/general/300x300/GirU09O_Ai7HxlR6x2tgu8bcyV_o3r7OPf0VWjBs7QQ.jpg):

I've examined the Document's directory using iExplorer and the image is saved to the right path with the right name also I've tried to download the image by hand and put to the Documents directory and it worked. The image that I downloaded was with size 900kbyte, but the image that the code downloads was 3.1mbyte.

My code is:

```
UIImage *staticResortMap = [self downloadImageWithStringURL:resort.staticPhotoPath];
staticPhotoPath = [_fileManager saveImage:staticResortMap usingName:kImageBaseNameResortStaticMap];

- (UIImage *)downloadImageWithStringURL:(NSString *)stringURL {
    NSURL *photoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:photoURL];
    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
}

- (NSString *)saveImage:(UIImage *)image usingName:(NSString *)name {
    NSString *directory = [_documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDirectoryNameResortResources];
    NSError * error = nil;
    [_fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:directory
            withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                             attributes:nil
                                  error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"error creating directory: %@", error);
    }

    NSString *path = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .9f) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    return path;
}
```

I've tried using the saved image like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"/var/mobile/Applications/0C62F621-C823-4DE2-B1CD-796EBAA459FB/Documents/resort_resources/static_map_image.jpg"];
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"/var/mobile/Applications/0C62F621-C823-4DE2-B1CD-796EBAA459FB/Documents/resort_resources/static_map_image.png"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"static_map_image.jpg"];
UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"static_map_image.png"];
```

My problem is that when I save an image to the Document directory and I am trying to allocate using the function `[UIImage imagenamed:""]` the function return nil. But when I save an image from other URL from the internet is working. It sounds silly a pid I know.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve image documents sub directory like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *pathToDocumentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath =  [pathToDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"resort_resources"]; // Get path of your subdirectory 

filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"static_map_image.jpg"];// Full path of your image

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with **Swift**

```
// Get a document url (path)
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}

if let image = UIImage(named: "example.png") {
    if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) {
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
        try? data.write(to: filename)
    }
}
```